# XAMPP/wordpress heartburn

Tags: xampp, linux

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my WordPress install to act correctly. I followed the video provided by Rajendra Patel on youtube. Here's the link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMycmTPl8nc. Anyway, when I go to localhost i get Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page. It says in bold to replace the /var/www/html/index.html with something, but I've done a little reading and I'm just so green behind the gills I don't know what to replace it with.

I was, however, able to get port 81 hooked up to wordpress during the install.So running the URL: http://localhost:81 gets me the standard bitnami wordpress page on local. The access wordpress page goes to 404. The phpmyadmin link goes to a login page that doesn't get called if i just use the regular local host url. Have I created an empty database or can I get this hooked up to my current install?

Any help is appreciated. Sorry if this is redundant, but I'm a super duper novice at both Linux and WordPress.

ps. i'm using ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: have you checked other videos or articles? I would be wary of any videos that don't have speech in them, you also don't have to use XAMPP/Bitnami, there are lots of other options for setting up a local dev environment

Comment: yeah, i think that i'm at the point where i need to rip the wordpress install and do as detailed here: http://localhost/dashboard/docs/install-wordpress.html. i realize that you may not see it if you don't have xampp installed but i think the docs are available on their website.

Comment: I thought that if he's replaced the .html file in /var/www/html/ it would allow me to call it up with the browser. I've come to a point where I'm using the above file, also located here: https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/get-started/. I'll come back and let you guys know if it works. One issue that has come up is that during the install of WP through bitnami it won't let me pick port 80. have XAMPP running at the same time, but i thought that the point was to use XAMPP to serve up WP.

Comment: ok, bump that. Go to this guys here: https://labinator.com/how-to-install-wordpress-locally/. This will give you the blow by blow down to routing your directory. Note when you get to step 2 of wordpress install you click on the folder link that says wordpress and it all pops up. Thank you https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/736/tom-j-nowell for reminding me there is more than one way to skin a cat.